# JBoss Clustering Failed to create netty connection of HornetQ in one node

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cluster-computing, hornetq, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to set up clustering among JBoss EAP 6.4 instances. These instances includes Hornetq configuration. So I am using standalone-full-ha configuration.

I am starting instances using following commands

standalone.bat -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b ip1 -u 230.0.0.4  -Djboss.node.name=node1

standalone.sh -b ip2 -c standalone-full-ha.xml -u 230.0.0.4 -Djboss.node.name=node2 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100

When I start servers (it does not matter which one is started first), second node throws Hornetq exception after restart. Second node is installed on Linux system. If I do not start node with Windows OS, second node does not throw any exception. I have read some tutorials but I did not get reason.

This is configuration for messaging system.

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.4">
        <hornetq-server>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
            <clustered>true</clustered>
            <cluster-password>${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:CHANGE ME!!}</cluster-password>
            <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </netty-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </connectors>

            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </netty-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </acceptors>

            <broadcast-groups>
                <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
                    <socket-binding>messaging-group</socket-binding>
                    <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
                    <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
                </broadcast-group>
            </broadcast-groups>

            <discovery-groups>
                <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
                    <socket-binding>messaging-group</socket-binding>
                    <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
                </discovery-group>
            </discovery-groups>

            <cluster-connections>
                <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                    <address>jms</address>
                    <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
                    <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
                </cluster-connection>
            </cluster-connections>

            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>

            <address-settings>
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                    <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes>
                    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>

            <jms-connection-factories>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                    <ha>true</ha>
                    <block-on-acknowledge>true</block-on-acknowledge>
                    <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
                    <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
                    <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
                </connection-factory>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <transaction mode="xa"/>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>

            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue">
                    <entry name="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ">
                    <entry name="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-queue name="SiGuardServerQueue">
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/queue/siguard/serverQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-topic name="SiGuardClientTopic">
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/topic/siguard/clientTopic"/>
                </jms-topic>
                <jms-topic name="SiGuardNodeTopic">
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/topic/siguard/nodeTopic"/>
                </jms-topic>
            </jms-destinations>
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>
```

This is log message about clustering.

```
12:41:01,656 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (Thread-26 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=da26d613-275d-11e8-9916-47aa4871a389-1826611860)) HQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@3c035549 [name=sf.my-cluster.4f838502-2756-11e8-a545-6f0f06e5030f, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.my-cluster.4f838502-2756-11e8-a545-6f0f06e5030f, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=da26d613-275d-11e8-9916-47aa4871a389]]@26a4798f targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@3c035549 [name=sf.my-cluster.4f838502-2756-11e8-a545-6f0f06e5030f, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.my-cluster.4f838502-2756-11e8-a545-6f0f06e5030f, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=da26d613-275d-11e8-9916-47aa4871a389]]@26a4798f targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=netty, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=5545&host=158-226-195-192], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1921711354[nodeUUID=da26d613-275d-11e8-9916-47aa4871a389, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=netty, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=5445&host=158-226-195-193, address=jms, server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=da26d613-275d-11e8-9916-47aa4871a389])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=netty, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=5545&host=158-226-195-192], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
```

This is exception thrown in second node.

```
 2:18:59,991 ERROR [org.hornetq.core.client] (Thread-8 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=4f838502-2756-11e8-a545-6f0f06e5030f-1656714538)) HQ214016: Failed to create netty connection: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(OioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:109) [netty-3.6.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(OioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:69) [netty-3.6.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:634) [netty-3.6.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:207) [netty-3.6.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:229) [netty-3.6.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:182) [netty-3.6.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:653) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1257) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1103) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:253) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:882) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:670) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:654) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl$3.run(ServerLocatorImpl.java:632) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:105) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: - In this particular case the issue was caused by network misconfiguration. There was a firewall between to cluster nodes that was preventing cluster from formation. The fact that the system could not keep up with executor creation rate. As soon as one was created it was used up by netty trying to establish a connection, activity that was continuously failing.Determine if the remote HornetQ instance is reachable.

Comment: - Check the messaging subsystem to determine the netty-connector and socket-binding being used.
~~
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.4">
                <hornetq-server>
                    <cluster-password>${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:CHANGE ME!!}</cluster-password>
                    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
                    <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
                    <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
                    <connectors>
                     <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
...
~~

Answer (score 0):

Windows firewall ports for socket binding "messaging" as defined in standalone.xml should be opened for hornetq to connect.

```
<socket-binding-group name='standard-sockets' default-interface='public' port-offset='${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}'>
    <socket-binding name='management-native' interface='management' port='${jboss.management.native.port:9999}'/>
    <socket-binding name='management-http' interface='management' port='${jboss.management.http.port:9990}'/>
    <socket-binding name='management-https' interface='management' port='${jboss.management.https.port:9443}'/>
    <socket-binding name='ajp' port='8009'/>
    <socket-binding name='http' port='${http.port:8080}'/>
    <socket-binding name='https' port='8443'/>
    <socket-binding name='jgroups-mping' port='0' multicast-address='${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}' multicast-port='45700'/>
    <socket-binding name='jgroups-tcp' port='7600'/>
    <socket-binding name='jgroups-tcp-fd' port='57600'/>
    <socket-binding name='jgroups-udp' port='55200' multicast-address='${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}' multicast-port='45688'/>
    <socket-binding name='jgroups-udp-fd' port='54200'/>
    <socket-binding name='messaging' port='5445'/>
    <socket-binding name='messaging-group' port='0' multicast-address='${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}' multicast-port='${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}'/>
    <socket-binding name='messaging-throughput' port='5455'/>
    <socket-binding name='modcluster' port='0' multicast-address='224.0.1.105' multicast-port='23364'/>
    <socket-binding name='remoting' port='4447'/>
    <socket-binding name='txn-recovery-environment' port='4712'/>
    <socket-binding name='txn-status-manager' port='4713'/>
    <socket-binding name='stomp' port='8675'/>
    <socket-binding name='stomp-secure' port='8676'/>
</socket-binding-group>
```